# Rails 3 - NoMethodError: undefined method for nil:NilClass in each Iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration

I'm iterating over an array of instances of a Rails model. Here is my code:

```
product_details.each do |product_detail|
  product_detail.label = Backend::ProductGroup.where(product_group_number: product_detail.product_group).first.label

end
```

The attribute 'label' from 'product_detail' isn't an attribute from my Rails ActiveRecord model. I added it with attr_accessor in my class definition. I did this, because I wanted to add this attribute dynamically, only when I need to do this. When I ran the code without the 'each' iteration in my rails console it works just fine. But when I execute the above code I get the following error message:

NoMethodError: undefined method 'label' for nil:NilClass

Did I do something obviously wrong?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have several `product_detail` items that have no matching `product_group`.  So calling `.first` on the empty collection returns `nil`.  To get around the error, you can test if the product_group was found before proceeding:

```
product_details.each do |product_detail|
  product_group = Backend::ProductGroup.where(product_group_number: product_detail.product_group).first
  product_detail.label = product_group.label if product_group
end
```

You can also do this more efficiently like so:

```
group_labels = BackEnd::ProductGroup.
                 where(product_group_number: product_details.map(&:product_group)).
                 inject({}){|m, g| m[g.product_group_number] = g.label; m}
product_details.each do |product_detail|
  product_detail.label = group_labels[product_detail.product_group]
end
```

This will result in a single database call to grab all related groups, and put the labels in a keyed hash for easy discovery and assignment.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick and really useful reply, although it is a bit embarrassing for me because you were absolutely right. ;)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but why is it that the 'label' attribute is always null when I try to send those 'product_details' as json to the client? I've tried to serialize it with the 'to_json' method before the render action but that doesn't helped. It is really curious because in the debugger right before the serialisation the attribute 'label' is set with the right value. Afterwards it is null. Can't I send objects with dynamically added attributes to the client?

Comment: @knoefel: You can, but that depends on how you serialize it.  The default behavior is likely going to serialize only the table-backed attributes - you'll need to modify this for your purposes.